# Does the following code implictly creates an SWT UI thread?

Tags: swt

I have a small query.I just started out with the SWT programming and learnt that all the updates to a UI component be made from a UI thread and a UI thread is the one in which the Display object has been created. So, in the following code, even though I do not create any thread explictly, does a thread gets created in the background?

```
package com.zetcode;

import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Point;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Rectangle;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

/**
 * ZetCode Java SWT tutorial
 *
 * In this program, we show a window in
 * the center of the screen
 *
 * @author jan bodnar
 * website zetcode.com
 * last modified June 2009
 */

public class SWTApp {


    public SWTApp(Display display) {

        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setText("Center");
        shell.setSize(250, 200);

        center(shell);

        shell.open();

        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
          if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
          }
        }
    }


    public void center(Shell shell) {

        Rectangle bds = shell.getDisplay().getBounds();

        Point p = shell.getSize();

        int nLeft = (bds.width - p.x) / 2;
        int nTop = (bds.height - p.y) / 2;

        shell.setBounds(nLeft, nTop, p.x, p.y);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display display = new Display();
        new SWTApp(display);
        display.dispose();
    }
}
```

Source:http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javaswttutorial/introduction/

Thanks,
Pavan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No new thread is created, but your thread becomes the UI thread.

Comment: By 'your thread' are you referring to main method?..can we assume it to be a thread?

Comment: By "your thread" I mean the thread in which the main method is executed.